# Getting localtime with values_list in django

Tags: django

I have set `settings.TIME_ZONE = Europe/Paris`.

In django I get dates like this:`dates = (...).values_list('started_at', flat=True)`

But the resulting dates are in UTC.

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 28, 2, 23, 54, 361753, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

How do I get the dates in my local time without converting all those dates like following?:

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime
dates = [localtime(d) for d in dates]
```

Comment: what's the value of `settings.USE_TZ`?

Comment: `settings.USE_TZ = True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values from the database will always be in UTC. As described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/):

> When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user's time zone in templates and forms.

So if you want the local time in your Python code you indeed need to convert them yourself, just as you described.

Comment: Is it? AFAIK, Django will store datatime in UTC if `settings.USE_TZ` is `False`

Comment: I was very used to the `obj.started_at` being in my timezone (`obj = MyModel.objects.get(...)`). I guess `.values_list(...)` acts different.

Comment: @Ariunbayar: There's nothing special about `values_list()`. If `USE_TZ` is `True` and `obj.started_at` is in your local time, then there's something strange about your setup. Are you using the database [`TIME_ZONE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/) setting? It's also possible for the database connection to do its own timezone conversions.